# jQuery freezes between show and hide

Tags: jquery, html, css

see [**this fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/9k3b2cp1/) it shows `#red` on hover over `#btn` and hide it on mouse leave, simple.

```
$(function() {
    $('#btn').hover(function(){
        $('#red').stop().show(2000);
    }, function(){
        $('#red').stop().hide(2000);
    });
})
```

but just try to Hover, Leave, and Hover again in less than two seconds, `#red` freezes somewhere in between.

as last method called on hover line is `show()`, why doesn't it show completely again?

thanks

Comment: Seems to work for me on Version 40.0.2214.111 m. Broken on IE 10

Comment: @PaulSasik created the fiddle with 40.0.2214.111 m ! maybe you didn't hover-leave-hover fast enough?

Comment: I hovered fast and slow. Can't recreate it on Chrome. On IE, yes, i can recreate the problem.

Comment: Just got it to happen on Chrome. But it's very inconsistent. I feel like I need to hover/leave/hover 5 or more times to get it to happen. And each move is about .250 seconds. Well under the 2 seconds...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can easily reproduce the problem when I test it in Chrome, IE 11 and Firefox. Apparently the `show` doesn't work when the element isn't completely hidden. Adding a `hide` before the `show` makes it behave nicely:

```
$('#btn').hover(function(){
    $('#red').stop().hide().show(2000);
}, function(){
    $('#red').stop().hide(2000);
});
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/Guffa/9k3b2cp1/2/